# Find values which are closest to given values and return the row index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, return-value

Is there an easy way to find the nearest values in a numpy way?
And get as output the row number?

As an example: I want to find the rows, which are closest to

```
value= [0.33, 0.66, 0.99]
```

I have the data

```
random= pd.DataFrame()
random=random.assign(data='')
random.data= np.linspace(0.1,1.0,10)

data
0     0.1
1     0.2
2     0.3
3     0.4
4     0.5
5     0.6
6     0.7
7     0.8
8     0.9
9     1.0
```

As an answer, the function should now give out the rows which have the `data` closest to the `value`

```
answer= [2,6,9]
```

I am trying something with

```
idx = (np.abs(random.data - value)).argmin()
```

but I am struggling with the loop and the rows as an answer.

Anyone knows an easy way? :-)

Comment: You could have a look to numpy.searchsorted (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) or to pure-python "bisect" library (https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/bisect.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'data':np.linspace(0.1, 1.0, 10)})

values = [0.33, 0.66, 0.99]

d = np.abs(values - df.values)

np.argmin(d, axis=0)
```

This returns the indices of the *first* closest value. In the case you have more than one values in dataframe that are equally close to a value in `values` and want to return all the indices, you can use:

```
np.where(d == d.min(0))[0]
```

instead of `np.argmin`.

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

value = 0.15

random= pd.DataFrame()
random=random.assign(data='')
random.data= np.linspace(0.1,1.0,10)

answer = []
temp = []
for d in random.data:
    temp.append(np.abs(d - value))

for i in range(0, len(temp)):
    try:
        answer.append(temp.index(min(temp), i, i+1))
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)

print(answer)
```

In a function, it would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def get_min(data, value):
    answer = []
    temp = []
    for d in data:
        temp.append(np.abs(d - value))
    for i in range(0, len(temp)):
        try:
            answer.append(temp.index(min(temp), i, i+1))
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)
    return answer

random= pd.DataFrame()
random=random.assign(data='')
random.data= np.linspace(0.1,1.0,10)

print(get_min(random.data, 0.15))
```

regards